# npm http-server "page not found" when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, httpserver

I am starting the http-server using the command: **http-server build** after **npm run build**. The server works fine and I can navigate the pages but whenever I start to refresh a page or access it via URL it gives me the 404 error.

```
[Tue Jul 31 2018 10:26:12 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)] "GET /key-word-mapping" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36"
[Tue Jul 31 2018 10:26:12 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)] "GET /key-word-mapping" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I didn't had this issue when using **npm start**. Is there a way to fix this?

I am using ReactJS with Router in order to navigate pages.

This is my App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component<{}> {
  render(): React.Node {
    return (
      <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/signin" component={SigninPage} />

            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={ResultsPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/key-word-mapping" component={WordMappingPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/words" component={WordsPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/mapped-seniority" component={MappedSeniority} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/mapped-department" component={MappedDepartment} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </LocaleProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you navigating pages without accessing via URL?

Comment: Could you paste your package.json content?

Comment: You need to use server that will redirect to home page when you open non existed page it seems that http-server don't have this feature. Or use url hash instead of history API, don't know how react router works maybe there is option to disable html5 urls like in angularJS.